# How to get filename after "_" in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have this problem where I want to get the filename and insert it into a cell in excel but I need a specific word to be inserted in the excel, right after the "_". For example, the excel file is **01 Monthly report_January.xlsx** so the filename inserted to the cell should be **January** excluding the file type eg. **xlsx**, **xls**. How to achieve this? The filename is from the currently opened excel.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser,, plz [edit] post and be specific that from where you are getting file name,,, like are U getting current file name, using Excel function or getting from Internet ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Take a look at the `instr()`, `trim()`, and `right()` functions in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=LEFT(MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("_",CELL("filename"))+1,99),FIND(".",MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("_",CELL("filename"))+1,99))-1)
```

[image]

For a file whose name is like:

**alpha_June.xlsx**

**EDIT#1:**

A slightly shorter formula:

```
=MID(LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND(".",CELL("filename"))-1),FIND("_",CELL("filename"))+1,LEN(CELL("filename")))
```